# How does Google know who I met and in what room?

Tags: privacy, google, geolocation

Last week I took my wife to see her new doctor doctor who is independent and located in the same office at 7 other doctors. Today I noticed that the doctor's name was on the map not the office building not any of the other doctors but the specific doctor that that my wife met. And I never even met the doctor nor have I received any emails from this person just one phone call during the week. I never went inside the office but was just in the waiting room yet out of the seven doctors she was identified in Google Maps. How?

Comment: Per office wifi?

Comment: Perhaps a calender event you created, or the reverse lookup Google done when the Doc called you.

Comment: your wife's Google account?

Comment: maybe your wife found the dr from google...

Comment: Nope none of these  obvious creepy Google Ways

Answer (score 2):

#### Facts

If you type the building address on Google map Your wife's doctor name appear but not the others docs working in the same office.

#### Google map

If you know the other doctor's names, try to search them on google map. 
By doing this lookup, we can eliminate the possibility that this doctor of yours is the only one among his colleague who is registered on google map.

If none of the other doctor's name point to the building, you can assume that, for google map, your wife's doc is the only one who works there.

Google map relies on its users, it waits for them to feed the app with data. For example, if I activate the location on my phone (Android), Google will trace my movement, ask me to rate the place where I eat, if my work office has an elevator, or if my train station is open still open at 1 am.

Most of the time google map questions are accurate. On rare occasion, the app has misunderstood my movement. For instance, I was chilling in a coffee shop, the app thought I was in the dentist's waiting room next door and asked me if patients can receive a treatment without an appointment.

Google is a data gathering freak.

#### Answer

- Being logged into her Google account, your beloved one went in the building with the location activated on her phone.
- Your wife's doctor, you or your wife book the appointment in google calendar using Mail address that Google knows about.